# OpenCV inRange() is working for RGB but not HSV color space

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

Ive generated a scatter plot of my image in RGB and HSV format and am using `inRange()` to threshold a single color from eyeballing the plot.

To get exact RGB and HSV values I'm using paint.net's color picker to get the RGB value and then an [RGB to HSV converter](https://toolstud.io/color/rgb.php?rgb_r=111&rgb_g=112&rgb_b=71&convert=rgbdec) to get the HSV values.

[image]

The pixel colors and the scatter plot are generated by:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\b_.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


pixel_colors = img.reshape((np.shape(img)[0]*np.shape(img)[1], 3))
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=-1., vmax=1.)
norm.autoscale(pixel_colors)
pixel_colors = norm(pixel_colors).tolist()

h, s, v = cv2.split(img_hsv)
fig = plt.figure()
axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")

axis.scatter(h.flatten(), s.flatten(), v.flatten(), facecolors=pixel_colors, marker=".")
axis.set_xlabel("Hue")
axis.set_ylabel("Saturation")
axis.set_zlabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

I need to extract the yellow from my image. As mentioned I am using paint.net color picker to get the RGB values of light yellow and dark yellow. And then use the converter to get the HSV values for the `inRange()` function.

```
light_yellow = (60, 89, 97)    # HSV VALUES
dark_yellow = (61, 36.6, 43.9)

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, light_yellow, dark_yellow)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

but the result generated is a black image, however if I use the RGB values directly of light and dark yellow and use the RGB image, not the HSV converted image, the segmentation works.

```
light_yellow = (249, 249, 125)    # RGB VALUES
dark_yellow = (111, 112, 71)

mask = cv2.inRange(img, light_yellow, dark_yellow)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
```

[image]

Although the above is RGB segmentation, I feel it may be improved in HSV. Why is my HSV range not giving an output?

Comment: There is no single consistent definition of HSV. You should always use the same software to convert if you want to compare colors.

Comment: Just a small extra suggestion, try to make the colors of the plot look more uniform, (with no shadow ) if not some points won't be visible once you filter. (like the grey ones to the left of the yellow ones)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it is expressed in the documentation of [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor). When it is CV_8U the H value which normally goes from 0 to 360, it is divided by 2 and goes from 0-180. The S and V values are usually percentage (0-100%) and they go from 0-255.

So your value:

```
light_yellow = (60, 89, 97)    # HSV VALUES
dark_yellow = (61, 36.6, 43.9)
```

Should be more like:

```
# (H/2, (S/100) * 255, (V/100) * 255) 
light_yellow = (30, 227, 247)    # HSV VALUES
dark_yellow = (31, 93, 112)
```

Now you have another problem, inRanges looks for valus inside the low and high range, not by light and dark yellow. So your limits should be:

```
low = (30,93,112)
high = (31, 227,247)

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, low, high)
```

One more thing, I would use a bigger range for the H color... 30-31 is quite small, maybe 20-32 is better?

Comment: Can you explain, in-depth, how you went from the second step:

``` 
light_yellow = (30, 227, 247)    # HSV VALUES
dark_yellow = (31, 93, 112)
````
to the third, where the values were:

```
low = (30,93,112)
high = (31, 227,247)
```

I understand the previous step where you simply "normalized" the values according to the range that openCV uses, but I don't understand how you derived the last part.

Comment: @RaleighL. sorry for the late answer. I only took the min value in both colors to generate the low values and took the max value between both colors to generate the  high values. more or less like: `low = (min(light_yellow[0], dark_yellow[0]), min(light_yellow[1], dark_yellow[1]), min(light_yellow[2], dark_yellow[2]))` for the low, and the same but using max for the high.